# How to handle bad data quality in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-quality

The code below is a sample of grouped data containing Temperature (bear in mind it's temperature taken of a human being in hospital) from our source system.

Obviously the data is horrible but wondered if it was possible to somehow turn this data into and INT as we have a UOM (Unit of measure) field so we only need the number.

Data issues:

88 degree is obviously Fahrenheit and not Celsius
3635 would be 36.35
.368 would be 36.8
37.3. would be 37.3
.37.7 would be 37.7
377 would be 37.7
.3.8 would be 38

I think any other variation should just be excluded invalid data to be fair as cannot accurately make an informed assumption.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    [Temperature] VARCHAR(500),
    [Count] VARCHAR(50)
                 )
INSERT INTO @Test ([Temperature],[Count])
 VALUES 

('34.4                oC',' 9   '),
('36.02               oC',' 1   '),
('36.36               oC',' 3   '),
('36.5                oC',' 5593    '),
('36.5.               oC',' 1   '),
('36.6.               oC',' 2   '),
('36.74               oC',' 2   '),
('36.82               oC',' 2   '),
('37.36               oC',' 2   '),
('37.49               oC',' 4   '),
('40                  oC',' 1   '),
('88                  oC',' 1   '),
('        3635                  oC','   1   '),
('  .368              oC',' 1   '),
('33.5                oC',' 1   '),
('35.2                oC',' 84  '),
('35.20               oC',' 1   '),
('35.99               oC',' 1   '),
('36.35               oC',' 2   '),
('37.3.               oC',' 1   '),
('39.5                oC',' 5   '),
('86                  oC',' 1   '),
('         356                  oC','   12  '),
('         364                  oC','   72  '),
('         379                  oC','   9   '),
('         385                  oC','   2   '),
('        3535                  oC','   1   '),
('  .37.7             oC',' 1   '),
('35.5                oC',' 290 '),
('35.87               oC',' 1   '),
('36..6               oC',' 1   '),
('36.25               oC',' 2   '),
('36.45               oC',' 2   '),
('36.62               oC',' 2   '),
('36.68               oC',' 5   '),
('36.8.               oC',' 2   '),
('37.03               oC',' 5   '),
('37.1                oC',' 3610    '),
('37.16               oC',' 3   '),
('37.2      oCC000715799',' 1   '),
('37.27               oC',' 2   '),
('37.91               oC',' 1   '),
('38.9                oC',' 28  '),
('63.5                oC',' 1   '),
('71                  oC',' 1   '),
('         377                  oC','   8   '),
('               36.5 oC',' 1   '),
(' 3.4                oC',' 3   '),
(' 3.7                oC',' 3   '),
('36.59               oC',' 1   '),
('36.67               oC',' 5   '),
('37.13               oC',' 1   '),
('37.18               oC',' 1   '),
('37.24               oC',' 1   '),
('39.7                oC',' 5   '),
('76                  oC',' 2   '),
('80                  oC',' 2   '),
('         347                  oC','   1   '),
('         352                  oC','   2   '),
('         368                  oC','   64  '),
('        3602                  oC','   1   '),
('        3688                  oC','   1   '),
('  .36.4             oC',' 1   '),
('  .8                oC',' 1   '),
(' 3.2                oC',' 2   '),
('34.3                oC',' 5   '),
('34.9                oC',' 20  '),
('35                  oC',' 124 '),
('35.81               oC',' 1   '),
('36.17               oC',' 2   '),
('36.23               oC',' 1   '),
('36.37               oC',' 2   '),
('36.38               oC',' 4   '),
('36.42               oC',' 1   '),
('36.76               oC',' 2   '),
('37..2               oC',' 1   '),
('37.00               oC',' 4   '),
('37.07               oC',' 6   '),
('37.12               oC',' 2   '),
('37.2                oC',' 3151    '),
('37.48               oC',' 2   '),
('39.                 oC',' 1   '),
('39.2                oC',' 9   '),
('39.9                oC',' 2   '),
('         370                  oC','   1   '),
('30.1                oC',' 1   '),
('34.1                oC',' 2   '),
('34.8                oC',' 17  '),
('35.43               oC',' 1   '),
('36..8               oC',' 2   '),
('36.05               oC',' 1   '),
('36.21               oC',' 4   '),
('36.31               oC',' 2   '),
('36.41               oC',' 1   '),
('36.58               oC',' 8   '),
('36.8                oC',' 8134    '),
('36.81               oC',' 3   '),
('36.88               oC',' 2   '),
('36.89               oC',' 2   '),
('36.99               oC',' 4   '),
('37.01               oC',' 6   '),
('37.14               oC',' 3   '),
('37.33               oC',' 1   '),
('37.37               oC',' 6   '),
('37.44               oC',' 1   '),
('37.59               oC',' 2   '),
('38.5                oC',' 85  '),
('39.4                oC',' 9   '),
('78                  oC',' 2   '),
('92                  oC',' 1   '),
('         361                  oC','   19  '),
('         383                  oC','   1   '),
('         391                  oC','   1   '),
('        3642                  oC','   1   '),
('        3699                  oC','   2   '),
('               37.6 oC',' 1   '),
('35.59               oC',' 1   '),
('35.69               oC',' 1   '),
('35.90               oC',' 1   '),
('36..9               oC',' 1   '),
('36.08               oC',' 2   '),
('36.27               oC',' 1   '),
('36.365              oC',' 1   '),
('36.51               oC',' 1   '),
('36.78               oC',' 4   '),
('36.84               oC',' 1   '),
('36.85               oC',' 3   '),
('36.97               oC',' 2   '),
('37.29               oC',' 1   '),
('37.3                oC',' 2306    '),
('37.8                oC',' 730 '),
('38.08               oC',' 1   '),
('38.4                oC',' 113 '),
('38.49               oC',' 1   '),
('38.7                oC',' 53  '),
('39.3                oC',' 10  '),
('70                  oC',' 2   '),
('         357                  oC','   5   '),
('         362                  oC','   49  '),
('         396.8                oC','   1   '),
('        3700                  oC','   1   '),
('        3752                  oC','   1   '),
('  .381              oC',' 1   '),
(' 0.37               oC',' 1   '),
(' 3.1                oC',' 1   '),
('14                  oC',' 1   '),
('27                  oC',' 1   '),
('34.2                oC',' 5   '),
('34.5                oC',' 22  '),
('35.9                oC',' 633 '),
('36.44               oC',' 2   '),
('36.57               oC',' 1   '),
('36.65               oC',' 1   '),
('36.66               oC',' 3   '),
('37.04               oC',' 7   '),
('65.9                oC',' 1   '),
('82                  oC',' 2   '),
('         118                  oC','   1   '),
('         358                  oC','   6   '),
('         381                  oC','   2   '),
('         396.6                oC','   1   '),
('        3704                  oC','   1   '),
('        3801                  oC','   1   '),
('      ',' 195340  '),
('                362 oC',' 1   '),
('  .374              oC',' 1   '),
(' 3.6                oC',' 3   '),
('26.5                oC',' 1   '),
('35.0                oC',' 28  '),
('35.79               oC',' 1   '),
('36..7               oC',' 1   '),
('36.00               oC',' 2   '),
('36.18               oC',' 1   '),
('36.48               oC',' 4   '),
('36.49               oC',' 3   '),
('37.19               oC',' 2   '),
('37.46               oC',' 1   '),
('37.9                oC',' 465 '),
('38.12               oC',' 1   '),
('39                  oC',' 25  '),
('         351                  oC','   2   '),
('         369.                 oC','   1   '),
('         389                  oC','   1   '),
('        3736                  oC','   1   '),
('  NULL    ',' 7   '),
('35.98               oC',' 1   '),
('36                  oC',' 2948    '),
('36.28               oC',' 1   '),
('36.69               oC',' 1   '),
('36.72               oC',' 2   '),
('36.77               oC',' 4   '),
('36.98               oC',' 7   '),
('37.05               oC',' 3   '),
('37.06               oC',' 2   '),
('37.15               oC',' 3   '),
('37.25               oC',' 5   '),
('37.26               oC',' 3   '),
('37.39               oC',' 3   '),
('37.42               oC',' 1   '),
('37.68               oC',' 3   '),
('38.3                oC',' 160 '),
('38.6.               oC',' 1   '),
('         376                  oC','   18  '),
('        3617                  oC','   1   '),
('        3703                  oC','   1   '),
(' 3.8                oC',' 2   '),
(' 7.6                oC',' 1   '),
('30.6                oC',' 1   '),
('34                  oC',' 3   '),
('34.7                oC',' 9   '),
('35.06               oC',' 1   '),
('35.7                oC',' 324 '),
('35.74               oC',' 1   '),
('36.01               oC',' 2   '),
('36.1                oC',' 1517    '),
('36.12               oC',' 1   '),
('36.4                oC',' 5001    '),
('36.6                oC',' 7044    '),
('36.79               oC',' 5   '),
('36.86               oC',' 1   '),
('36.90               oC',' 1   '),
('36.93               oC',' 1   '),
('37.30               oC',' 1   '),
('37.92               oC',' 1   '),
('38.                 oC',' 5   '),
('38.6                oC',' 65  '),
('38.8                oC',' 46  '),
('97                  oC',' 1   '),
('         354                  oC','   4   '),
('         355                  oC','   5   '),
('         365                  oC','   107 '),
('        3654                  oC','   1   '),
('35.8                oC',' 495 '),
('36.09               oC',' 6   '),
('36.2                oC',' 2526    '),
('36.3.               oC',' 1   '),
('36.47               oC',' 1   '),
('36.53               oC',' 2   '),
('36.9                oC',' 5449    '),
('37.0                oC',' 1209    '),
('37.1.               oC',' 1   '),
('37.32               oC',' 2   '),
('37.38               oC',' 5   '),
('37.45               oC',' 1   '),
('37.5                oC',' 1477    '),
('37.6                oC',' 1101    '),
('37.80               oC',' 1   '),
('38.1                oC',' 215 '),
('40.2                oC',' 1   '),
('62                  oC',' 1   '),
('         366                  oC','   61  '),
('         375                  oC','   28  '),
('16                  oC',' 1   '),
('34.0                oC',' 1   '),
('35.                 oC',' 3   '),
('35.1                oC',' 61  '),
('35.23               oC',' 1   '),
('35.58               oC',' 2   '),
('36.                 oC',' 59  '),
('36.03               oC',' 1   '),
('36.16               oC',' 2   '),
('36.94               oC',' 2   '),
('37.08               oC',' 7   '),
('37.21               oC',' 1   '),
('37.47               oC',' 1   '),
('39.8                oC',' 3   '),
('         346                  oC','   1   '),
('         353                  oC','   2   '),
('         369                  oC','   57  '),
('         374                  oC','   28  '),
('        3677                  oC','   1   '),
('               37.4 oC',' 1   '),
('34.6                oC',' 15  '),
('35.3                oC',' 74  '),
('35.4                oC',' 120 '),
('35.6                oC',' 320 '),
('36.06               oC',' 1   '),
('36.07               oC',' 2   '),
('36.14               oC',' 1   '),
('36.19               oC',' 1   '),
('36.54               oC',' 1   '),
('36.71               oC',' 1   '),
('36.92               oC',' 1   '),
('37.50               oC',' 1   '),
('37.54               oC',' 1   '),
('37.7                oC',' 836 '),
('39.0                oC',' 8   '),
('39.6                oC',' 3   '),
('60                  oC',' 1   '),
('         127                  oC','   1   '),
('         336.8                oC','   1   '),
('        1500                  oC','   1   '),
('               36.4 oC',' 1   '),
('36.0                oC',' 829 '),
('36.3                oC',' 3192    '),
('36.56               oC',' 3   '),
('36.63               oC',' 2   '),
('36.7                oC',' 6348    '),
('36.73               oC',' 3   '),
('36.96               oC',' 4   '),
('37.                 oC',' 64  '),
('37.4                oC',' 1861    '),
('37.69               oC',' 1   '),
('38.01               oC',' 1   '),
('93                  oC',' 1   '),
('         351.                 oC','   1   '),
('         371                  oC','   24  '),
('         372                  oC','   45  '),
('         373                  oC','   30  '),
('        3722                  oC','   1   '),
('  .3.8              oC',' 1   '),
('26.1                oC',' 1   '),
('35.97               oC',' 4   '),
('36.61               oC',' 3   '),
('37                  oC',' 4890    '),
('37.02               oC',' 3   '),
('37.66               oC',' 1   '),
('38                  oC',' 367 '),
('38.0                oC',' 72  '),
('38.2                oC',' 225 '),
('39.1                oC',' 22  '),
('         359                  oC','   14  '),
('         360                  oC','   3   '),
('         363                  oC','   49  '),
('         367                  oC','   112 '),
('         378                  oC','   8   ')


Select 

*
from @Test
```

Comment: You already know what your data looks like and what you'd want it to look like. What's stopping you from changing it?

Comment: Nothing that the question really this is data in a model table and I need to get it to a valid INT value into the DW.

Comment: That comes down to implementing the rules you've made up in T-SQL, which breaks down into a lot of sub-problems using `CASE`, `LIKE`, `PATINDEX` etc. What to you is "obvious" will have to be coded in painstaking detail for the benefit of the computer. For more complicated cases, you may need client-side cleansing that can make use of regular expressions, since T-SQL's string manipulation isn't very advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will get you close.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE
WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Temperature, 'oC', ''), ' ', ''), '.', '')) = 1
THEN CONVERT(INT, (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Temperature, 'oC', ''), ' ', ''), '.', '')))
ELSE NULL END AS TemperatureValue
FROM @Test
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine but doesn't account for the DQ issues which we are keeping in as this is what was recorded

```
TRY_CAST(REPLACE(Temperature, 'oC', '') AS DECIMAL(19,8))
```

Comment: I wasn't working trying to convert to INT so went with the easy out!